# change background image by user in android

Tags: android, background

I have 2 images `bg.jpg` and `bg2.jpg` in `drawable-hdpi` folder in my app.

I want show list of picture then user select one picture for background image for app.

And who i can get list of file in drawable-hdpi folder

Comment: store the user selected image in a boolean variable in shared preference and show the background image dynamically simple

Comment: who i can get list of file in drawable-hdpi folder

Comment: you cant get that but you can certainly save the user selected choice then show the background accoring to the choice

Comment: tank you for your help Illegal Argument

Answer (score 0):

Google--> Android How to change background dinamically --> 10000000 results --> first result--> A friend of stackoverflow:

[how to change the xml background in android dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226732/how-to-change-the-xml-background-in-android-dynamically)

```
LinearLayout root=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
if(select 1st picture)
{root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_image1);}
else
{root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_image2);}
```