# How do I add a new page to an Android app?

Tags: java, android

Apologies for the basic question, but I can't really find the answer online. Possibly because I'm not sure what I need to be searching for!

I have created a simple one page app following a guide. At the top there is a menu button, under that 'Settings'. I want to make it so that when the Settings button is clicked it takes you to a new settings page and allows the user to change the background colour, font colour or something simple like that.

However, I can't work out how to actually create a new page.  I tried creating a new class and linking the intent under the action_settings bit in the main .java file, but that didn't work for me.

Please could someone give me some guidance?

GitHub repo: https://github.com/LewisLebentz/Quoter

Comment: Take a look at Android Activities: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html also has a quick how to with its tutorial.

Comment: How-to for settings: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the settings button is on the action bar then follow these steps:

1) Create a new activity by right-clicking on the Java folder > New > Activity > Blank Activity. This will automatically create a layout file and a Java class. It will also automatically register the activity in the manifest.

2) Next you want to go to the Quoter.java file. Add the following code to it.
@Override

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        // This code will start the new activity when the settings button is clicked on the bar at the top.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Quoter.this, newActivityName.class);
        startActivity(intent)
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

That's it! When you click the settings button, it should start a new activity! Let me know if it does not work!

By the way, you can search for "how to switch activity on button press in Android".

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Feel like I'm starting to get the hang of things now. Although it looks like a fairly difficult task to allow the user to change the background colour..

Comment: Yea it is quite difficult in my opinion. You would need to create a button to create a dialog that shows the different colors. When the user selects a color, you have to dynamically change the background color. [This is how you would do it] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226732/how-to-change-the-xml-background-in-android-dynamically) (the dynamically changing part)

Comment: Hmm, thought that would have been something simple to change! That's still a bit above my understanding, might ask a question here, or skip trying to do that for now and come back when my skills have improved. Could you recommend any particular tutorials for beginners?

Comment: In my opinion, you should skip trying to do that for now. There are many great tutorials for beginners. This tutorial on [Udemy] (https://www.udemy.com/android-lollipop-complete-development-course/?dtcode=O332Z492YtoO) is what I started with. It is for $499 but the site usually puts sales often that go as low as $10, the price at which I bought it at, so keep checking often. This tutorial is really good and is what I started with.

Comment: Meanwhile, watch these to learn the basics: [Slidenerd's beginner videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzrGAZnMOMQ&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa) and [Darek Banas's beginner videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBD4xhH5vIE&index=1&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSPjWpLPFEfOCbezi6vATIh). Let me know if you have any other questions :)